# Cannot query across one-to-many for property in NestJS Postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, many-to-many, one-to-many

That's the updateEntity.ts

```
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator'
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm'
import { Company } from './company.entity'

@Entity('countries')
export class Country extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string

  @ManyToOne(() => Company, (company) => company.locations, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'company_id' })
  countryId: Company[]
}
```

CompanyEntity.ts with the location field

```
@OneToMany(() => Country, (country) => country.countryId, { eager: true })
  locations: Array<Country>
```

and here is the function where I want to update the properties

```
async update(id: number, updateCompanyDto: UpdateCompanyDto) {
    const newLocations = updateCompanyDto.locations.map((location) => Country.create(location))
    updateCompanyDto.locations = newLocations
    const status = await Company.update(id, updateCompanyDto)
    if (status.affected <= 0) {
      throw new HttpException('This company does not exist', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    }
    return status
  }
```

First time working with OneToMany and ManyToMany, and if I have the request body like this

```
"locations": [{"name":"Paris"}]
```

I'm getting an error "Cannot query across one-to-many for property locations"
I just want to be able to update the companies

Answer (score 0):

It's okay because if you need to update,create or delete data from Location entity,you need to query using that entity not from joined entity